# ActiveMQ Durable Subscriber with jmsMessageId

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm new to ActiveMQ and trying to find anything that explicitly outlines how JMSMessageID behaves with durable subscribers and selectors, however, I am struggling to find much.

As an example: *JMSType = 'car' AND color = 'blue' AND weight > 2500* as a selector. Each subscriber will only receive messages from the topic where the criteria match. When each receives said messages are the JSMMessageID unique for each subscriber or are they unique for the entire topic before it was filtered by the selector for the subscriber.

If not is there a way that I can get the JSMessageID to be unique for each subscriber so that it can be used as a form of sequence number using custom messageID layout: 1, 2, 3... ad infinitum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Message ID is set by the producer at the time of send, the broker passes along a copy of the message to each Topic subscription (durable or not) with the message ID that it was sent with.  You cannot alter the ID the broker uses that value to track the message and ensure that it is preserved until each subscription that it was dispatched to or stored for has acknowledged it.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me - so there is no way for the brokers to set a sequence number of sorts for each durable subscriber of the messages that they receive?